# No ios development certificate found and No unexpired provisioning profiles found

Tags: ios, xcode

Tonight I decided to submit my new app to the AppStore, I admit - I was shocked of how horrifyingly
complicated and ridiculously confusing this process is. I managed to submit all the information in iTunes Connect and proceeded to Archive my Application, I did that but then all hell broke loose .. I tried to verify my App but received the error "no development cert. .. contact the admin" well, I am the admin of my account and this certificate is active and installed.

My next steps were to uninstall the Dev and Distribution Profiles&Certificates on my Mac and install them again ... now, after this - it was event impossible to archive my app. I get the following errors
in Xcode: No unexpired provisioning profiles found , and the Organizer: Code Signing error - No ios development certificate found.

I hope that someone can give me any guidelines of how to solve this problem, This problem is really weird - all my certificates are active, and i do have Dev Certificate which could be seen from these screens:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the application name match exactly?

Comment: VibesRadio is hte name of the App, which other naming should be matched exactly, I also added another confusing confrontation as a screenshot of my post

Comment: hhaha , yeah I did it but.. no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with you step by step:

1- first send me this information marked in the attached image below
[image]

2- Then send me the info marked in red here too.
[image]

I would ask you to do something after that.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, i figured out the connection between these bundle IDs, it is really strange that during creation of these IDs in DevCenter - there is no emphasizing of how important these things are to match exactly

Answer (score 1):

It would be extremely helpful when you do 'figure out' the solution to your problem that you share what you figured out rather than just 'i figured out the connection between these bundle IDs'.  I know it isn't the first thought when you do solve your problem, but you could help someone else solve the same problem.